# Printing simple data from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I am learning Laravel by doing some basic tasks.

I am wanting to print data from a controller to the view for a profile page.

Current code I have for my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
     $userInfo = array(
          'accountType' => 'Developer',
          'username' => 'Sys',
          'email' => '123@example.com',
          'firstName' => 'Greatest',
          'lastName' => 'Forever',
          'gender' => 'M'
      );

      $posts = array(
        'fromUser' => 'Bob',
        'msg' => 'Hello World!',
        'sentTime' => '2016-07-07 18:01:00'
      );

      $friends = array(
        'Bob', 'Jim', 'Speed'
      );
}
```

My view currently has nothing in as things I have tried haven't worked.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

You need to pass data to a view like this:

```
return view('your.view', ['userInfo' => $userInfo, 'posts' => $posts, 'friends' => $friends]);
```

Or:

```
return view('your.view', compact('userInfo', 'posts', 'friends'));
```

Then you can use these variables in a blade view:

```
@foreach ($friends as $friend)
    {{ $friend }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: The line     return view('your.view', ['userInfo' => $userInfo, 'posts' => $posts, 'friends' => $friends]);    goes inside the "class AccountController" section?

Comment: You should create action inside this class, put your logic there and add `return view` part. Please read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers  Also, I'd really recommend you to read some Laravel book or some introduction tutorial at least.